# Trying to Change Position of Map to Sticky

Tags: html, css

I have a map element wrapped inside of a container and I'm trying to change its position to sticky (as opposed to relative). I have text that I would like to scroll over the map as the viewer scrolls down, however when I open up the inspection tools I see the position of the #map element reverts back to relative, despite it being sticky in my actual code. When I change it to sticky in the browser, it works fine. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="mapContainer" class="container-map">

<div id="map" style="position: sticky;" class="leaflet-container 
leaflet-touch leaflet-retina leaflet-fade-anim leaflet-grab leaflet- 
touch-drag leaflet-touch-zoom" tabindex="0"> 

</div>

<div id='sections'>
    <div>
        <h1>Operation Entebbe</h1>
        <p class="text">
            <span class="text-decorate">O</span>Sample Text
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
#mapContainer{
        position: relative;
}



#sections{
        z-index: 99;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 640px;
        position: relative;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
}


#sections > div{
        background: white;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: .75;          
        transition: 0.5s;

}


#sections > div p.text {
        display: block;
        color: #000000;
        z-index: 10;
}



#sections > div.graph-scroll-active{
        opacity: 1;
}



#map {
        margin-left: 40px;
        z-index: 3;
        width: 500px;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        top: calc(50% - 250px);
}



#map svg {
        z-index: 2;
}



#map svg {
        -webkit-transition: transition .6s;
        -moz-transition: transition .6s;
        -ms-transition: transition .6s;
        -o-transition: transition .6s;
        transition: transition .6s;
}



@media (max-width: 925px)  {
        #map{
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: 0px;
            float: none;
}

#sections{
            width: auto;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0px auto;
}

#sections > div{
            background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
            padding: 10px;
            border-top: 1px solid;
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
            margin-bottom: 80vh;
}

pre{
            overflow: hidden;
}

h1{
            margin: 10px;
}
}


#map {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: sticky; 
}


svg {
    position: relative;
}
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: add `!important` after `position: relative;` such as `position: relative !important;`. It is possible there is another style that is being applied overriding yours.

Comment: this worked. thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Only use `!important` when you have to. It's meant as more of a troubleshooting tool than a permanent solution. Dig down and find which style sheet is causing the conflict and adjust it.